# Unable to load resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just new to angularjs. I am trying to test simple controller in my index.html. But when i am running it on my localhost i am getting an error :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Here is my folder structure:

```
angulartesting
-bower_components
-index.html
-script.js
```

Here is my index.html file:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app="store">
<head>
  <!-- SCROLLS -->
  <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
 <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

  <!-- SPELLS -->
  <!-- load angular and angular route via CDN -->
  <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
  <div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <h1>{{store.product.name}}</h1>
    <h2>${{store.product.price}}</h2>
  </div>
     <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my script.js:

```
// create the module and name it scotchApp
    // also include ngRoute for all our routing needs
(function(){
     var app = angular.module('store', []);
     app.controller('StoreController',function(){
        this.product=gem;
     });
     var gem = {
        name:'Gaurav',
        price:'220'
     }
})();
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?
I am running it on my local server.

Comment: is the error coming from a line in the javascript? usually along with a 404 error you will get the url or the file that it failed to find

Comment: Please update the error message in your question what you are getting exactly.

Comment: no its not coming from the javascript line @Scott Selby

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I've just removed forward slashes before script sources and added `ng-app` attribute.

```
    <!-- index.html -->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html  ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
      <!-- SCROLLS -->
      <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
     <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

      <!-- SPELLS -->
      <!-- **Removed forward slashes before script sources** -->
      <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
        <h1>{{store.product.name}}</h1>
        <h2>${{store.product.price}}</h2>
      </div>
         <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I am still getting the same error: [Tue Mar 22 2016 12:09:46 GMT+0530 (IST)] "GET /index.html" Error (404): "Not found"

Comment: You have not yet loaded the index.html on your local server. It seems you have not configured your local server correctly. How you are using local server.

Comment: I have installed http-server using npm package and i move into the directory where my files are there and i run http-server from the terminal. If you can tell me how can i configure my local server than it will be a great help.

Comment: Just install it via $>npm install -g http-server and go to your app root folder where index.html is located, open command prompt and type http-server and hit enter.

Comment: I did the same earlier.

Comment: I've just installed http-server and started a server using on `http-server` in the root of the folder where index.html is located. It started and I navigated to http://localhost:8080/#/ and my app started without a problem. it required **no configuration**. Further I will recommend you to show us your app hierarchy (folder structure) so we can analyze.

Comment: I have already given the folder structure in my question above. angulartesting is the name of the folder which contains index.html file.

Comment: @gauravtiwari I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/1419/) for your code and it seems perfectly fine with minor adjustments. but I'm sorry I can't understand your problem with your information provided because as you described everything should work fine.